# Most efficient way to find all objects in between two indexes

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

Assuming you had data like this

```
var data = [
  {id: 4},
  {id: 0},
  {id: 3},
  {id: 2},
  {id: 1}
]
```

And this maps to some UI like rows in a table. A user clicks on id:0 then the user clicks on id:2, how do I get all items in between those two IDs? The part I'm trying to figure out is how to do this efficiently because the datasets here can be quite large (10s of thousands).

My best answer to this is the following but wondering if there's any faster methods to this:

```
var startIndex, endIndex;

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (firstElement == data[i].id) {
      startIndex = i;
    }
    if (lastElement == data[i].id) {
      endIndex = i;
    }
    if (startIndex !== undefined && endIndex !== undefined) {
      break;
    }
} 

var newData = data.slice(startIndex, endIndex + 1)
```

Comment: Nope, thats sensible enough - you only enumerate once and break out as soon as you can. But presumable you need the collection to be sorted before you can `slice` it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You could just simplify it to `data.filter((obj) => obj.id >= Math.min(startIndex, endIndex) && obj.id <= Math.max(startIndex, endIndex));` or something similar. You can’t make it more efficient.

Comment: why not store the index along the `id` in the table and use it direcly without searching for the index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on these answers and my testing my original code is plenty optimized already. The others gave answers really around either shortening it or making it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Tens of thousands is not that large for an `O(n)` scan, and you can't do better than `O(n)` since you need to look at each item.

To make the code a little cleaner, you can use `findIndex` to start from there

```
let startIndex = data.findIndex({ id } => id === firstElement), endIndex;
let endIndex;
for (var endIndex = startIndex; data[endIndex].id !== lastElement; i++) {
  if (endIndex === data.length) { endIndex = -1; break; }
}
if (endIndex !== -1) {
  var newData = data.slice(startIndex, endIndex + 1)
}
```